# How do I use Request-SPOUpgradeEvaluationSite command?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, spo, sp-online

In Microsoft's documentation, I see the `Request-SpoUpgradeEvaluationSite` command listed. I have a few questions about this command. First of all, from what I understand this creates a copy of a site collection, but where can I find the copy? Second of all, will the second site keep the same permissions as the old one? And finally, I tried to run the command, but I got an error saying `This operation has been deprecated.` What operation should I run instead? Is there a way to use this command even though it is deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Microsoft's documentation does not state this, it's likely that this cmdlet no longer works. The purpose of the cmdlet is to create a copy of a site collection to evaluate an upgrade to the experience level/build of your site collection. This cmdlet would have been relevant to those running SharePoint 2010 in their Office 365 tenant long ago, before it was upgraded either automatically or by running [Upgrade-SPOSite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/upgrade-sposite?view=sharepoint-ps)

Since updates are now incremental in SharePoint Online (you are always on the latest version of SharePoint), it's likely that these cmdlets will no longer work.

If you would like more information on the cmdlet, you could raise a [documentation issue via GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-docs-powershell/blob/master/sharepoint/sharepoint-ps/sharepoint-online/Request-SPOUpgradeEvaluationSite.md).